# Tcm is finding tests, but they all fail

Tags: automation, coded-ui-tests, tcm

Been scratching my head for a while with this and I thought I would ask here. I am trying to run automated tests with tcm via command prompt. I have set up and configured a test controller and agent. Tcm is recognizing all the tests from tfs when I list etc. Created a test run and the results came back:
Total:128
Passed:0
Failed:128
Inconclusive:128
Does this have something to do with the Controller or Agent not being set up properly? Would tcm recognize the tests if they were not set up properly? I have set up a lab environment and I can access the controller PC.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Russ

Comment: Is it possible for you to watch them executing so you can see when/how they are failing?

Comment: The tests do not execute by tcm. It just tries to execute them comes up with the 128 failed. I can run them perfectly through visual studio (run all). When I try vstest and a test from the dll file, i can see it running (although it does fail because the pathname is too long, but that's a different issue).

Comment: Ok found an error in MTM for the test run 'The build directory of the test run either does not exist or access permission is required'. Looked where it points to and indeed the directory is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information that "The build directory of the test run either does not exist or access permission is required", from steps 6 and 7 of [this MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff472576%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

- [Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181716(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Define](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647547(v=vs.110).aspx) a build definition
- Copy a build directory with the relevant information into this solution

[This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7558ec75-d857-40b4-b04d-55979ea75ffe/error-starting-the-test-run-the-build-directory-of-the-test-run-either-does-not-exist-or-access?forum=vsmantest) may also have relevant information if the above doesn't work

Comment: Thanks! I will try this and let you know how I get on. Very useful info!